# Formal malloc to use realloc later

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

Below code is just an example which I use to come to the point later:

```
/* Extract digits from an integer and store in an array in reverse order*/

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int oct=316;
    int* array=malloc(0*sizeof(int*));  //Step 1
    int* temp;
    size_t size=0;
    while(oct/10>0 || oct%10>0){
        temp=realloc(array,++size*sizeof(int)); // Step2 requires Step1
        if(temp==NULL){
            printf("Can't reallocate memory");
            exit(-1);
        }
        else{
            array=temp;
        }

        array[size-1]=oct%10;
        oct/=10;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    printf("%d\n",array[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

The realloc reference [[1]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) states :

> Reallocates the given area of memory. It must be previously allocated
>   by malloc(), calloc(), realloc()...

Initially I compiled the code without step1 and on running it I got a segmentation fault. Then I included step1, now the code compiles fine. I don't want to allocate some space without finding an integer to store so I have used a size of **zero** with **malloc**. However malloc reference [[2]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) states :

> If size is zero, the return value depends on the particular library
>   implementation (it may or may not be a null pointer), but the returned
>   pointer shall not be dereferenced.

Now, I doubt my implementation is portable. How can I work around this issue?

I tried doing `int* array=NULL;` but I got a segmentation fault.

Comment: `realloc(array,++size);` --> `array = realloc(array,++size*sizeof(int)); `

Comment: Note that you should not write: `ptr = realloc(ptr, new_size);` assigning immediately to the variable you're using to hold the pointer to the space.  If the `realloc()` fails, you leak memory because you've overwritten the pointer with NULL.  You need to use some variant of: `void *data = realloc(ptr, new_size); if (data == NULL) { …deal with error… } ptr = data;`.

Comment: Using `malloc(0)` to initialize the pointer will work, but it is a bit wasteful.  Simply set it to NULL.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : Thankyou for the time & comment#2. In this case setting pointer to null by `int* array=NULL;` did not work for me. Even my approach of using zero in malloc  (or realloc) wouldn't guarantee me a NULL pointer(as return vapue). Am i right?

Comment: `int *array = NULL;` and `int *array = malloc(0);` both works in `array = realloc(array,++size*sizeof(int));`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can initiate `array` to NULL. In the man page for `realloc(void *ptr, size_t size)` you can read:

> If ptr is NULL, then the call is equivalent to malloc(size)

Moreover `realloc` does not change its parameter. It returns pointer to newly allocated/reallocated space. So, for reallocating you shall use a code like:

```
array = realloc(array,(++size)*sizeof(int));
if (array == NULL) { some error; }
```

Comment: For completeness: C11 (draft) 7.22.3.5/3 (http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.5p3)